# Using AngularJS persian date picker causes $parse error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using [this](https://github.com/AminRahimi/angular-bootstrap-persian-datepicker) date picker component, and [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ECgLrFmcJtYwTaxgzQQd?p=preview) is a plunk demonstrating its usage with `ui.bootstrap` version 1.3.3, When I want to use `min-date` option for date picker, angular gives me this error, any workaround for this issue?

```
 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Apr' is an unexpected token at 

column 5 of the expression [Wed Apr 05 2017 14:18:41 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard 

Time)] starting at [Apr 05 2017 14:18:41 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)].
```

Comment: error location is in date-picker-farsi.js line 83, because $parse service can not be used for parsing date object. request writer to give you solution

Comment: what is the workaround?

Comment: scope chaining inheritance is not implemented as excepted, so scope.$parent.$watch on $parsed date object is completely wrong. request library writer to give you solution or change his code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the owner of the project and he told me to use `min-date` on directive instead of options.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ECgLrFmcJtYwTaxgzQQd?p=preview) is working plunk